# MEF error "Only one batch can be composed at a time"

Tags: c#, azure, mef, azure-web-roles

I have a web-role which serves up a website in Azure.  This site uses the `[Import]` attribute to import the data repository.  This works fine for the most part, but under a moderate load, there are occasional errors which say `Currently composing another batch in this ComposablePartExportProvider. Only one batch can be composed at a time`.

How do I fix this error?  It has become a rather problematic bottleneck in the application, and I'm sure there is a (relatively) quick fix...  I should note that I'm using the `MEF.MVC4` assembly in Nuget.

My `Global.asax.cs` calls `RegisterMef` to set up the MEF side of things on `Application_Start()`.

```
public static void RegisterMef()
{
    var container = ConfigureContainer();
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MefControllerFactory(container));
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new MefDependencyResolver(container);
}

private static CompositionContainer ConfigureContainer()
{
    var assemblyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    var container = new CompositionContainer(assemblyCatalog, true);
    return container;
}
```

My `CompositionContainer` is set to be thread-safe, so I'm at a loss.  The creation policy is shared by default, so setting `SatifsyImportsOnce` wouldn't do anything.

Full Error:

```
Currently composing another batch in this ComposablePartExportProvider. Only one batch can be composed at a time.

    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

    Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Currently composing another batch in this ComposablePartExportProvider. Only one batch can be composed at a time.

    Source Error: 

    An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

    Stack Trace: 


    [InvalidOperationException: Currently composing another batch in this ComposablePartExportProvider. Only one batch can be composed at a time.]
       System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ComposablePartExportProvider.Compose(CompositionBatch batch) +390
       MEF.MVC4.MefControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +126
       System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +81
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +270
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +86
       System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12550511
       System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @overslacked - we had to ditch MEF...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by not using MEF.MVC4 because maybe its implement have error when moderate load (ex: 100 user request in the same time). I use MEF2 [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In Application_Start()

```
 var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(new DirectoryCatalog("bin"));
 var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog, true);
 ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MefControllerFactory(container));
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new MefDependencyResolver(container);
 CurrentContainer.SetCurrentContainer(container);
```